# Problems finding the runtime/space complexity for this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am struggling to find the space and time complexity for this algorithm that receives two trees and verifies if the second is a subtree of the first:

```
private static boolean matchSubtree(Node possibleRoot, Node rootSub) {
    Queue<Node> queueMain = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Node> queueSub = new LinkedList<>();

    queueMain.add(possibleRoot);
    queueSub.add(rootSub);

    while(!queueMain.isEmpty() || !queueSub.isEmpty()) {
        Node n1 = queueMain.remove();
        Node n2 = queueSub.remove();

        if(!compareNodes(n1.children, n2.children)) {
            return false;
        }
        queueMain.addAll(n1.children);
        queueSub.addAll(n2.children);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I think that the runtime complexity is `O(N + M)` (`N` being the number of elements in the first tree, `M` in the second), because I will iterate overall nodes of both trees.

The space complexity seems to be `O(N + M)` too, because in the worst case each queue will have N/M nodes (actually they will have N/2 or M/2 nodes, but this doesn't change anything). So it will also be `O(N + M)`.

Is this correct? I got a weird feeling about this.

Comment: What is `n` and `N`?

Comment: Just edited to make it clearer

Comment: The answer is yes and yes: you're iterating each node in each tree exactly once so it has runtime of O(N+M) and same goes for space